# Can extensions make use of service workers?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, service-worker

Can a firefox or chrome extension use service workers? Attempting to install one via a content script doesn't seem to work

```
Failed to register/update a ServiceWorker for scope (url)
```

And installing one via a background script seems to be failing too:

```
Registration failed with SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Content scripts run in "isolated world" so you can try to [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879) and [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources). Chrome extensions can also use workers in their own context e.g. in the background page.

Comment: @wOxxOm Service worker installation points at another file for the service worker code, usually (afaict) at the same path as the javascript from which the service worker was injected. So I'd have to make the service worker code be gettable from that source? Or am I missing something to this idea? Appreciate the idea!

Answer (score 0):

The service worker is installed if the storage is enabled.
But the storage is disabled if this Firefox setting is enabled: Preferences / Cookies and Site Data / Delete cookies and site data when Firefox is closed

Please check the [Mozilla ticket](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1418179) for details. Also you could test if the service worker works on the [test page](https://mdn.github.io/sw-test/)